# getting stock price from financial data

Tags: curated-data, finance

I would like to print only the stock price from below input , i have been trying since a couple of hours with no luck..this is what I did

```
Financial data for GE ={{{2016,1,4},30.4661},{{2016,1,5},30.4959},{{2016,1,6},30.0098},{{2016,1,7},28.7399},{{2016,1,8},28.2241},{{2016,1,11},28.353},{{2016,1,12},28.4125},{{2016,1,13},28.0157},{{2016,1,14},28.8292},{{2016,1,15},28.2637},{{2016,1,19},28.2637},{{2016,1,20},27.7776},{{2016,1,21},28.3629},{{2016,1,22},28.0157},{{2016,1,25},27.8173},{{2016,1,26},28.0852},{{2016,1,27},27.7776},{{2016,1,28},27.986},{{2016,1,29},28.8689}}

data4 = FinancialData["GE", "Price", {{2016, 1, 1}, {2016, 1, 29}}];
Print["Financial data for GE =", data4];


Print[" y coordinte value", lis[data4[1][0]]];
```

May I know where I am going wrong?

Comment: `data4[[All, 2]] // Column`

Comment: this is what I get when I try to run the examples of the documentation in 10.3.1 `{{2000,1,1},{2000,4,1}} is not a valid date range for FinancialData`, perhaps a bug?

Comment: Thank you Dr.belisarius....I was loooking for that...unfortunately i cannot mark your comment as solution....please advise me if there is anyway i can do it.

Comment: Bob's answer is more complete, don't need to post mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data4 = FinancialData["GE", "Price",
   {{2016, 1, 1}, {2016, 1, 29}}];
```

The tabular data

```
{{{Style["Financial data for GE", Bold],
     SpanFromLeft}, {"ISO Date", "Price"}},
   ({DateString[#1, "ISODate"],
       #2} & @@@ data4)} // Flatten[#, 1] & //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray] &
```

[image]

Incorporating the tabular data as `Tooltip`

```
DateListPlot[data4,
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Small],
   Tooltip[
      Point[#], 
      DateString[#[[1]], "ISODate"] <>
       "\n" <> ToString[#[[2]]]] & /@ 
    data4}]
```

[image]